# line break mailto command, dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, mailto

I know it sounds like a duplicate but the solution doesn't work for me:

```
mailtocommand += 'Pro: '+$("#prosurfername").val()+"%0D%0A";
$('#sendlink').attr('href', mailtocommand);
```

Doesn't make a line break.
Neither with this in between:

```
var mailtocommand = encodeURIComponent(mailtocommand);
```

What is the mailto command to insert a line break in dynamically (jquery) created mailto?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368), `%0D%0A` is the correct format for a new line, but it only applies to the body part of a mailto message.  Just go to the link and search for "line", but here are the relevant parts:

> 5 Encoding
>
> RFC 1738 requires that many characters in URLs be encoded. This
> affects the mailto scheme for some common characters that might
> appear in addresses, headers or message contents. One such character
> is space (" ", ASCII hex 20). Note the examples above that use "%20"
> for space in the message body.  Also note that line breaks in the
> body of a message MUST be encoded with "%0D%0A".

> ...

> A similar URL could have two lines with different "send" requests (in
> this case, "send current-issue" and, on the next line, "send index".)

> ```
> <mailto:infobot@example.com?body=send%20current-
> ```

```
 issue%0D%0Asend%20index>
```

Without seeing all of mailtocommand, I can't be certain of your problem.  It looks like you're adding the linefeed in properly, so my guess is that your setting of mailtocommand doesn't contain "body=" before you put the newline.